# What is the most efficient method to tackle pebble in sandal?

Tags: walking

Frequently I have a problem of pebble getting inside of my sandals from back side (red in the image). It travels through the sandal forcefully as I try to remove it without actually removing the sandals (white line in image). That pebble is thrown in front when I give it angular momentum to forcefully remove it (the yellow line). There are two problems I feel.
[image]

1  -  The pain it gives me as it hurts. And removing it by removing sandals within the public does not feel good.

2  -  (rare case) Some times the pebble that goes from the sandal (in direction of yellow line) it "hits somebody".

Is there any life hack to prevent the pebble from coming within sandals at the first place?

Comment: It also depends on how you take steps, try to not drag your feet while walking. Once I started walking correctly, pebbles inside my sandals became almost a non existent problem

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to prevent pebbles under your foot is to wear a form of sandal with enclosed heel, toe, and instep.  It's called a "shoe" or, in a more extreme form, a "boot".  Shoes, and especially boots, are much more resistant to pebble (and, to a lesser extent, sand) getting under the foot.

Comment: Never heard of one, could you provide a citation?